# convert a string value to decimal two digit

Tags: c#

I want to convert this "price" variable string to standard two digit 60.00 decimal value. How is that possible? any ready method available for that? thanks in advance

```
string price = "60.0000";
decimal _price = //asign value here. format will be 60.00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Parsing a string is something you learn on your first day in programming 101.

Comment: do a simple google search on `Convert.To` method also do one how `C# convert string to decimal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first parse the `price` and then use the `Round` method, in which you can specify the number of decimal places you want:

```
decimal _price = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(price),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try three ways:
First:

```
string price = "60.0000";
decimal _price = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(price),2);
```

Second:

```
string price = "60.0000";
decimal _price = Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(price),2);
```

Or the third and most recomended because of preventing errors:

```
string price = "60.0000";
decimal _price;
Decimal.TryParse(price, out _price);
_price = Math.Round(_price, 2);
```

In the third way you can assign _price on the beginning to some unrealistic price e.g.

```
decimal _price = -9999;
```

Than when the price is not a number that can be converted into decimal in _price will be -9999 and you know that there is some problem.